# shouldComponentUpdate not working in reactJS

Tags: reactjs

I need to update comments on UI once user comment on any post, I have a parent component (where listing of comments has been shown) and a child component(commentBox), I created a function which is been called after we update child component's data and pass that data to parent component, here is my code

```
handleCommentData(data,index){
    if(this.state.postContentData != undefined && 
       this.state.postContentData != null && 
             this.state.postContentData != ""){
        if(this.state.postContentData[index].comments == null){
            this.state.postContentData[index].comments = [];
        }
        this.state.postContentData[index].comments.push(data.data);
    }
}
```

here postContentData is an array in which a key of comments is present where comments is again a array of objects, i.e.,

```
postContentData = [{"createdOn":1531287979671,
             "updatedOn":1531290897575,
             "deletedOn":0,
             "postCreatedBy":{},
             "createdAt":1531290897575,
             "audioType":false,
             "videoType":false,
             "imageType":false,
             "id":"bc46aa71-84cd-11e8-a011-59c285e9b8c6",
             "title":"",
             "content":"text",
             "medias":null,
             "comments":[
                  {
                    "createdOn":1531290846743,
                    "updatedOn":1531290846743,
                    "deletedOn":0,
                    "postId":"bc46aa71-84cd-11e8-a011-59c285e9b8c6",
                    "id":"692f2270-84d4-11e8-a011-59c285e9b8c6",
                    "commentByUserId":"630d8660-833b-11e8-9584-c9f6295e7d94",
                    "commentUserName":"net",

                    "commentId":null,
                    "comment":"comment 10",
                    "status":0,
                    "replyCount":0,
                    "mediaType":"TEXT",
                    "deleted":false
                },
                {
                    "createdOn":1531290783811,
                    "updatedOn":1531290783811,
                    "deletedOn":0,
                    "postId":"bc46aa71-84cd-11e8-a011-59c285e9b8c6",
                    "id":"43ac7930-84d4-11e8-a011-59c285e9b8c6",
                    "commentByUserId":"630d8660-833b-11e8-9584-c9f6295e7d94",
                   "commentUserName":"net",
                   "commentId":null,
                   "comment":"comment 9",
                   "status":0,
                   "replyCount":0,
                   "mediaType":"TEXT",
                   "deleted":false
                  }
         ]
   }]
```

Now, shouldComponentUpdate is not working

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    for(let i=0; i < this.state.postContentData.length; i++){
        for(let j=0; j < nextState.postContentData.length; j++){
            if(this.state.postContentData[i].comments != null && 
                 nextState.postContentData[j].comments != null){
                if(this.state.postContentData[i].comments.length !== 
                    nextState.postContentData[j].comments.length){
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and render is not updating after handleCommentData function.

Answer (score 0):

You are using return inside of forLoop which isn't the correct way to go, since you need to decide whether to return true or false based on the fact that no data has changed

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    const shouldRender = false;
    for(let i=0; i < this.state.postContentData.length; i++){
        for(let j=0; j < nextState.postContentData.length; j++){
            if(this.state.postContentData[i].comments != null && 
                 nextState.postContentData[j].comments != null){
                if(this.state.postContentData[i].comments.length !== 
                    nextState.postContentData[j].comments.length){
                    shouldRender = true;
                } 
            }
        }
    }
    return shouldRender;
}
```